# Sum counts that are greater than a certain value in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, aggregate-functions

I have a query that groups people by zip codes. I want to be able to sum the zip code counts that have less than 10 people in them into 1 group.

Here is the query that groups the people by zip codes:

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN PatInfo.Zip IS NULL THEN 'Unknown Residence'
        ELSE PatInfo.Zip 
    END AS ZipCode,  
    COUNT(PatInfo.PatientProfileID) AS TotalPatient
FROM
    Encounter E 
JOIN 
    EncounterType ET ON E.EncounterTypeID = ET.EncounterTypeID        
JOIN 
    PatientInfo PatInfo ON PatInfo.PatientProfileID = E.PatientProfileID           
WHERE 
    YEAR(Visit) = 2016 
    AND ET.Description IN ('Office Visit', 'Outpatient Surgery', 'Emergency') 
    AND E.EncounterCounted = 1 
GROUP BY
    PatInfo.Zip
```

I would like to be able to sum the counts that have 10 or fewer and put them into 1 grouping. Something like this:

```
SELECT 
    'Other Zip Codes' AS ZipCode,  
    SUM(COUNT(PatInfo.PatientProfileID)) AS TotalPatient
FROM 
    Encounter E 
JOIN 
    EncounterType ET ON E.EncounterTypeID = ET.EncounterTypeID        
JOIN 
    PatientInfo PatInfo ON PatInfo.PatientProfileID = E.PatientProfileID           
WHERE 
    YEAR(Visit) = 2016 
    AND ET.Description IN ('Office Visit', 'Outpatient Surgery', 'Emergency')
    AND E.EncounterCounted = 1 
GROUP BY
    PatInfo.Zip
HAVING 
    COUNT(PatInfo.PatientProfileID) <= 10
```

But I get an error:

> Can't perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an
>   aggregate

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  Just created a subquery and summed it then unioned the 2 results:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN PatInfo.Zip IS NULL THEN 'Unknown Residence' ELSE PatInfo.Zip END AS ZipCode,  
       COUNT(PatInfo.PatientProfileID) AS TotalPatients
FROM Encounter E JOIN EncounterType ET ON E.EncounterTypeID = ET.EncounterTypeID        
        JOIN PatientInfo PatInfo ON PatInfo.PatientProfileID = E.PatientProfileID           
WHERE YEAR(Visit) = 2016 AND ET.Description IN ('Office Visit', 'Outpatient Surgery', 'Emergency')
        AND E.EncounterCounted = 1 
GROUP BY PatInfo.Zip
HAVING COUNT(PatInfo.PatientProfileID) > 10
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Other Zip Codes' AS ZipCode, SUM(TotalPatient) AS TotalPatients
FROM
(
SELECT 'Other Zip Codes' AS ZipCode,  
       COUNT(PatInfo.PatientProfileID) AS TotalPatient
FROM Encounter E JOIN EncounterType ET ON E.EncounterTypeID = ET.EncounterTypeID        
        JOIN PatientInfo PatInfo ON PatInfo.PatientProfileID = E.PatientProfileID           
WHERE YEAR(Visit) = 2016 AND ET.Description IN ('Office Visit', 'Outpatient Surgery', 'Emergency')
        AND E.EncounterCounted = 1 
GROUP BY PatInfo.Zip
HAVING COUNT(PatInfo.PatientProfileID) <= 10
) AS OtherZips
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
declare @year varchar(20)='2016'
set @year=@year +'-01-01'
--select @year
select DATEADD(month,datediff(month,0, DATEADD(month,-month(@year)+1, @year)),0)

;With CTE as
(
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN PatInfo.Zip IS NULL THEN 'Unknown Residence'
        ELSE PatInfo.Zip 
    END AS ZipCode,  
    row_number()over(partition by PatInfo.Zip order by PatInfo.Zip) AS ZipGroup
FROM
    Encounter E 
JOIN 
    EncounterType ET ON E.EncounterTypeID = ET.EncounterTypeID        
JOIN 
    PatientInfo PatInfo ON PatInfo.PatientProfileID = E.PatientProfileID           
WHERE 
    Visit >= @year
    AND ET.Description IN ('Office Visit', 'Outpatient Surgery', 'Emergency') 
    AND E.EncounterCounted = 1 
)

select ZipCode,ZipGroup from CTE
where ZipGroup<10
union all
select ZipCode,ZipGroup from CTE
where ZipGroup>=10
```

Comment: This does not work.  I get `Unknown Residence` listed the first 9 rows with the `ZipGroup` value of 1 - 9.  The ZipGroups that contain values of less than or equal to 10 are not grouped in 1 row.  They are all listed individually.

Comment: in that case,you have to throw some sample data and out you are expecting.